# How to switch from PDO connect to Mysql connect?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I did my coding parts with PDO connect.Its working in my dev server.But when I move it to live server its not working.I already posted the issue with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807113/whats-wrong-with-pdo-connection)

**Issue**

But the database connection with mysql is working fine.I tried to change the configuration part with the people they are in live server.They tried it but got failed.Now they don't want to go with PDO.They asked me to go with mysql_connect.

**Goal:** 
Instead of changing the entire code is there any possible idea to execute the query with the mysql connection.I don't want to change the entire database activity.Because it is used in many places.

Could you please help on this.

Comment: Why isn't it better to figure out what actually caused the issue?

Comment: This would be the ultimate example on why you should encapsulate and use abstraction. Are you sure this isn't just a server config issue? To enable PDO, I mean.

Comment: @JohnP: abstraction from what? It makes no sense to abstract from PDO (which in fact is abstract DBAL)

Comment: @zerkms server is not in my controll.I already send a lot of mails to the people.But they never get the solution for it.So cant able to figure out what they made the changes,and why its throwing an error.

Comment: @zerkms I meant having a fixed interface. Switching would be a matter of switching out the provider.

Comment: It must be very retarded hosting provider which does not support PDO Extension, otherwise you have provided wrong database server address.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any possible idea to execute the query with the mysql connection.

No.

Comment: Thanks.So I need to change it in all the places. :(