# Why can't I connect to a remote MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, firewall, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to understand “can't connect” mysql error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231168/how-to-understand-cant-connect-mysql-error-messages)

I have attempted to follow just about every tutorial I could find on this subject, to no avail. I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL database through PHP, but it seems like the connection is timing out or something. This is my PHP code:

```
$link = mysql_connect('remote-server-ip:3306', $username, $password);
if($link){
    echo "Connected.";
}else{
    echo "Not connected: ".mysql_error();
}
```

When I browse to that page, it loads for about 30 seconds before displaying this:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'remote-server-ip' (4) in /var/www/vhosts/*****/httpdocs/*****/*****.php on line 6
```

Here's what I've done on the remote server to try to allow this connection:

- Added IPtables rules to allow connections from my server.
- Set my.cnf to listen to all TCP requests
- Added users to my database that can connect from my server's IP

Still nothing seems to be working. I could really use some help here.

Comment: Did you remember to flush privileges? (Trivial, but still)

Comment: @DC_: And sticking to functions that are being deprecated is?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem This is simply a test file - I usually use PDO.

Comment: Firstly, set `default_socket_timeout` to 6 seconds in your local php.ini.. 30 seconds is way too long to wait. :)

Comment: @DC_ That makes no sense. Why not stick to what you normally use instead of *testing* with deprecated functions?

Comment: Is 'remote-server-ip' pingable from the machine where you're running the PHP?

Comment: try localhost instead of remote-server-ip:3306

Comment: @davidstrachan That would work if I were trying to connect to my local MySQL server, but I'm not :p

Comment: localhost is the host of both my remote servers. Try it & see

Comment: Solved by using [this PHP Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4000-PHP-Execute-remote-MySQL-queries-across-the-Web.html). It's a workaround, but it works.

Comment: Also, I disagree with the close vote. This is definitely not an _exact duplicate_, and the answers on the other question don't answer anything.

Answer (score 1):

If your waiting a period of time then it's likely the ip is not reachable. Try to ping the MySQL server first. Then try to telnet to it on port 3306. You should get a connection. Then see if you can connect to MySQL from the SQL server itself ie a local connection. Must do the basics first