# symfony2 : MySQL server error when trying to create a database

Tags: mysql, apache, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpmyadmin

i have just create an entity on symfony

i am now trying to create a database using the console command:

```
 php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

this generate this error :

```
     Could not create database for connection named `symfony`

    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

the /var/run/mysqld/ folder is actually not present in my computer !?

my app/config/parameters.yml :

```
  parameters:
database_driver:   pdo_mysql
database_host:     localhost
database_port:     ~
database_name:     symfony
database_user:     root
database_password: ~

mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_host:       localhost
mailer_user:       ~
mailer_password:   ~

locale:            en
secret:            ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

what's wrong ? 
what did i miss?
how can i have access to phpmyadmin on a symfony projet?

Comment: Change localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: i have tried this already :Could not create database for connection named `symfony`
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Comment: `show variables like 'socket';`(this behaves just like a select statement)...and you'll get the path of the running socket.

Then check the file permissions.

Comment: can u explain this in more details? i dunno how to use this show variables like 'socket'; command

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138959/confusing-pdo-only-problem-cant-connect-through-socket-access-denied-cant-co

Comment: i have seen that ...i don't understand where to place this :show variables like 'socket';

Comment: the etc/mysql folder contains only one file : my.cnf ....i am wondering if mysql is installed at all? is it stored elsewhere?

Comment: hmmm try reinstalling ur mysql

Comment: inside my.cnf file , it is written :[client]
port  = 3306
socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Comment: mysql was not installed properly indeed ....

Comment: if it happen to anyone : sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude upgrade
sudo aptitude install mysql-server

Comment: hmmm so u problem is resolved by reinstalling the mysql!!! kewl!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved it by re-sintalling mysql server

```
  sudo aptitude update sudo aptitude upgrade sudo aptitude install mysql-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **localhost** instead of 127.0.0.1 to connect in your parameters.yml. Worked for me on a ubuntu pc.